# How can I specify a condition on a PermissionEx in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to conditionally add an ACE to a directory. The [WiX documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permissionex.html) and XSD states that  is a valid child of util:PermissionEx, but I can't get it to work. Is it really supported?

I have this installer definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="test" Language="1033" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation" UpgradeCode="89028746-7cf3-42e7-8121-d0bf0140e2dd">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="test" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="Component_TokenFolder_HybridAgent" />
    </Feature>

    <Property Id="ISDOMAINCONTROLLER" Value="0"/>
    <Property Id="SERVICEUSERGROUP" Value="foo"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>      
      
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="AppDataFolder_HybridAgent" Name="FOO">
          <Directory Id="TokenFolder_HybridAgent" Name="Tokens">
            <Component Id="Component_TokenFolder_HybridAgent" Guid="b733054f-b0df-40fe-942a-a492fa8109a3">
              <CreateFolder>
                <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"/>
                <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="Administrators"/>
                <util:PermissionEx Read="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" ReadExtendedAttributes="yes" ReadPermission="yes" GenericRead="yes" User="[SERVICEUSERGROUP]">
                  <Condition>ISDOMAINCONTROLLER=0</Condition>
                </util:PermissionEx>
              </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  </Wix>
```

When I try to compile it with candle.exe in WiX 3.11, I get:

```
C:\onebranch\HybridAgent\src\deploy\Deployment\Deployment\test.wxs(30) : error CNDL0203 : The util:PermissionEx element contains an unsupported extension element 'Condition'.  The util:PermissionEx element does not currently support extension elements. Is the Condition element using the correct XML namespace?
```

Comment: It appears that <Condition> is a valid child for <PermissionEx> but not <util:PermissionEx>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PermissionEx` is a little bit of a tricky element. There is one that comes from the `WixUtilExtension` (the one you get from the `util:` namespace) and one that is built into the Windows Installer (the one you get from the default wix namespace).

Why are there two? Well, we added `util:PermissionEx` that could do permission things the normal `Permission` element could not. Then in Windows Installer 5.0 they added `PermissionEx` creating the collision.

So you want to make sure you are on the correct link:

1. [util:PermissionEx](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/permissionex.html)
2. [PermissionEx](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permissionex.html)

To answer your question, you can condition the `util:PermissionEx` by conditioning the `Component`. If you can adopt Windows Installer 5.0 (available in Win7+) then you could use the `PermissionEx` with its more fine-grained condition support.